# Reason behind the following output

Tags: c

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 char *prg = "char *prg = %c%s%c;main(){printf(prg,34,prg,34);} " ;
 void main (){
 printf(prg,34,prg,34);
 }
```

Reason behind the following output

**char *prg = "char *prg = %c%s%c;main(){printf(prg,34,prg,34);} ";main(){printf(prg,34,prg,34);}**

Comment: Because the code assumes an ASCII-based environment. Try `printf(prg, '"', prg, '"');` to have the same output in all environments. Also `void main()` should really be `int main(void)` (`int main()` is ok too)

Comment: It is not clear for what in that output you want a reason. Is there anything noteworthy you would like to highlight in the output. Assume that users read your code and think "Well, that is exactly the output this code should obviously produce and the reason is the code."

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to do here.

Comment: I need an explanation regarding the output.

Comment: Please tell us the specific part(s) of the output that you don't understand.

Comment: the content in *prg Is printed but in place of "%c%s%c"  the content is replaced, why is it embedded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the content in *prg Is printed but in place of "%c%s%c" the content is replaced, why is it embedded

That's the way [`printf()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_printf.htm) works - in the *format* (the first `prg` argument), each *conversion specification* (`%c`, `%s`) converts a subsequent argument (`34`, `prg`) according to the conversion specifier (`c`, `s`) and writes the result to the standard output.

Answer (score 0):

That program is a classical example of a program that prints its source code to `stdout`.  Ascii character 34 is the ascii literal for `"` which is needed to be able to print the delimiters of a C string without incurring in an infinite recursive problem.  There are some characters that cannot be used literally, as they are transformed by the compiler, one of these is `"`, which dissapears when compiled in a string literal, others are the escaped char literals `\n`, `\t`,... depending on that, convert into a different char literal.  This is the reason the source code must be all in one line (control chars transform themselves by the compiler), no `#include ...` statements must be allowed (because it ends in a newline), and other things like this.

Compile it and rearrange it (you have modified it, for clarity, on posting) so you can output the exact same source code as you give the compiler.

## Note

The program code, to mimic exactly its source form in the output, must be written as:

```
char*p="char*p=%c%s%c;main(){printf(p,34,p,34);}";main(){printf(p,34,p,34);}
```

without a trailing newline at the end of the line.

If you substitute `34` by `'\"'`, and p by its value, you'll get:

```
...
printf(
    "char*p=%c%s%c;main(){printf(p,34,p,34);}", 
    '\"', 
    "char *p=%c%s%c;main(){printf(p,34,p,34);}", 
    '\"');
```

that will form the original string, putting the right delimiters at the proper positions.  (note: the `%c` and `%s` in the third parameter are not further expanded)

## Note2

This program depends on ASCII encoding for `"`.  It should'n work on EBCDIC encodings (you must  use the encoding for `"`  instead of the number 34)